# Where can I find the RAS131 dust hood for a Skil 1817 router?

Tags: woodworking

I have been searching for a dust-collection device for my Skil 1817 fixed-base router, and I can't seem to find anything.  I keep coming upon the same press release that indicates it is compatible with the "RAS131 dust hood", but I can't find that anywhere (Google, Amazon, Skiltools, Home Depot, Lowes, Ace, etc.).

Does anyone know where I can find this or another compatible accessory?

Comment: have you tried contacting [Skil Customer Service](http://www.skiltools.com/en/CustomerService/ContactUs/) directly & asking them?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've contacted them and am waiting to hear back.  I'll add any information here as soon as they respond.

Comment: I just spoke with customer service again and they told me that RAS131 is the correct part number, but that it is obsolete and there is no stand-in for it.  I'm going to see if anyone else in customer service has other suggestions, and then consider returning the router to the store rather than rigging up something with duct tape :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke with a second person in customer service and they said the same thing.  RAS131 is the correct part number, but it's no longer manufactured.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to parts i found is this

http://www.powertoolspares.com/tool/skil/spares-and-accessories-for-router-1830/f015183003/spares/

I cant find any hoods?

Answer (score 0):

Call Bosch directly at one of their service centers (they own Skil).  The fixed based dust extraction hood is RAS-131 and the plunge based hood is RAS-132.  I called the Anaheim, CA service location and they sold it to me.  I don't think it matters which center you buy from as they all put their orders in to be shipped from Arkansas.  The number I called was 800-334-4151.

Good luck.